# plotting Elliptic curve in matlab

Tags: matlab, elliptic-curve

I did wrote this code to plot elliptic curve on Matlab but I wonder if it is really what it should be :

```
function y=plotCurve(x,p)
for i=1:length(x)
    if(gcd(x(i),p)~=1)
        x(i)=inf;
    end
end
x(find(x==inf))=[];
y = x.^3+5.*x.^2+x;
y=mod(y,p);
k=sqrt(x.^3+10.*x.^2+x);
plot(x,k);
hold on
plot(x,-k);
xlim([min(x) max(x)]);
end
```

I tried to follow exactly classroom steps :

1) Check if x is in $Z_p$

2) Calculate $y^2$ (which in my example is y)

I do use this code in range of -10:10 with no float number between.